# SQL Server stored procedure with parameters for table name, ID field, ID field value that is uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, uniqueidentifier

I have about 12 tables in the database that are simple baseline data. As an example, I have `Role` and `Status`. These tables have an ID that is a `uniqueidentifier`. I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will allow me to pass the table name, name of the ID column, and the value I want.

I've tried this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_TABLE_DATA_BY_ID]
    @table      nvarchar(50),
    @tableid    uniqueidentifier,
    @value      uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECKALE @cmd AS nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd = N'select * ' +
                'from ' + @table +
                'where ' + cast(@tableid as nvarchar) + '= @value'

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
END
```

The procedure adds fine. But when I execute the procedure I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure GET_TABLE_DATA_BY_ID, Line 0
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

Is this even possible? Otherwise I would have to write many different procedures, not to mention the many different C# functions.

When I right click on the procedure and enter the values to test it creates this:

```
   DECLARE  @return_value int

   EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GET_TABLE_DATA_BY_ID]
                        @table = N'UserProfile',
                        @tableid = UserId,
                        @value = 'FB743B78-5B90-4A52-8177-6D516884700B'

   SELECT   'Return Value' = @return_value
   GO
```

I get the error :

> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

I redid the procedure per suggestion to this:

```
 DECLARE @cmd  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
          N'SELECT * 
            FROM @table
            WHERE tableid = @value',
    @param_list NVARCHAR(MAX) =
          N'@table  NVARCHAR(50),
            @tableid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
      @cmd
     ,@param_list
     ,@table
     ,@tableid;
```

When I do this in a new query window, I get the right data:

```
 select * from UserProfile where UserId = 'FB743B78-5B90-4A52-8177-6D516884700B'
```

But it doesn't work when I execute the proc with those values -

```
  Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
  Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '@value'.
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
  Incorrect syntax near '@value'.
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, but don't concatenate string, use @param_list for sp_executesql

Comment: @lad2025 can you give me an example of what you mean?  I'm an SQL novice.

Comment: Shouldn't `@tableid = UserId,` be `@tableid = 'UserId',`?

Comment: Confirm this or deny: You want to `select * FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = 'long-guid-xyz'`

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do.

Comment: So tableid should be NVARCHAR/SYSNAME not guid

Comment: @lad2025 you lost me with that last comment?

Comment: Column name  'UserId' is string.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit parameters:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5c10/20/0)**

```
DECLARE
  @tablename NVARCHAR(100)    = 'tab1',
  @tableid   NVARCHAR(100)    = 'a',
  @value     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '2FD22D07-E128-4133-ABA9-9B75215CB465'

DECLARE
  @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
          N'SELECT * 
            FROM '  + QUOTENAME(@tablename) +
           'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableid)  + ' = @value'

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
  @cmd
 , N'@value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER'
 , @value
```

Comment: Would this be in the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand one thing in your SPROC `'where ' + cast(@tableid as nvarchar) + '= @value'` do you columns have GUID names?

Comment: Yes, the ID field is the uniqueidentifier, which I get from using the GUID process in C#.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand you correctly, please edit question and add table + sample data.

Comment: I try to execute procedure by right clicking on it and I am presented with the values to enter.  I enter the table, table id field and a value that I know is in the table. I get this error: Incorrect syntax near '-', which is telling me that the unique field should be set in quotes but when I do that I get Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.